# How to plot 4 graphs in one screen for twinx or twiny method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot two y-axis and one x-axis, for only one picture in one graph window i know how to do , but how to change this code to draw 4 pictures in one graph window?

```
ax1 = axes()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

x = np.arange(100)
y1 = np.random.rand(100)
y2 = np.random.rand(100)

ax1.plot(x,y1,'-r')
ax1.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax2.fill_between(x,0,y2,color='b',alpha=0.5)
ax2.set_ylim(0,2)

ax1.set_ylabel('Red')
ax2.set_ylabel('Blue')
```

Comment: Are you looking for [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)?

Comment: @Patol75 i am familiar with simple subplots with one y-axis, here i want to plot subplots with two y-axis

Comment: Let's say you call subplots in such a way: `fig, (ax, bx, cx, dx) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)`, you can still twin each axis in the same way as you describe in your question. Would it be what you are after?

Comment: @Patol75 please can you add example for this ?

Comment: See below. Also, sorry for the mistake above, I always make it: even though subplots generates 4 axes, they are packed into two lists as there are both multiple rows and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way to go about it. I have only twined one axis, but indeed all axis can be treated similarly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
axTx = axarr[0, 0].twinx()
x = np.logspace(-1, 1, 100)
axarr[0, 0].plot(x, x, linewidth=2, color='xkcd:azure')
axTx.plot(x, 1 / x, linewidth=2, color='xkcd:avocado')
axarr[0, 0].tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='xkcd:azure')
axTx.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='xkcd:avocado')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]